# how to populate text boxes based on dropdownlist selection mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC, and very new to JQuery.  I'm attempting to populate textboxes based on a dropdownlist selection.  My Product model contains the fields ProductId, Name, and Price.  I want to populate the ProductId and Price fields in my QuoteDetails based upon the product Name chosen.  My controller action is as follows:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(int quoteId, int quoteDetailId)
        {
            var items = db.Products.ToList();
            ViewBag.ProductData = items;


            ViewData["QuoteId"] = quoteId;
            ViewData["QuoteDetailId"] = quoteDetailId;
            return PartialView("EditQuoteDetail", new QuoteDetail { QuoteId = quoteId, QuoteDetailId = quoteDetailId, ProductId = 1, ProductName = " ", Amount = 1, ListPrice = 0, Discount = 0, Price = 0 });
        }
```

The relevant portion of the partial view EditQuoteDetail is as follows:

```
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="ProductId", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DropDownList("ProductName", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "Name", "Name"), new { @id = "ProductName" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="Price", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The script I am using to attempt to populate the ProductId and Price fields is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ProductName').change(function () {
            $('#ProductId').val($(this).val());
            $('#Price').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I make the dropdown list selection, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do those element IDs exist on the page?  Is the `change` handler executed at all?

Comment: I added the ids (see above).  Still, nothing happens when i change the dropdown list selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found an answer.  travis.js started me on the right path when he said the BeginCollectionItem helper was overtaking my HTML, so I had to use id contains syntax to make it work.  The working jQuery (in the parent view) is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("change", '[id*="ProductList"]', function () {
                    $.post("/QuoteViewModel/GetProduct", { pId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                        $("[id*='ProductId']").val(data.ProductId);
                        $("[id*='Price']").val(data.Price);
                    });
                });
              });
            </script>
```

And the controller action (thanks Usman) is as follows:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetProduct(int pId)
        {
            var data = db.Products.Find(pId);
            return Json(data);
        }
```

Whew!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the script you are populating `dropdown` 
`ViewBag.ProductData, "Name", "Name"`  by Name so the `id` of the `dropdown` will also be its `Name` and also `ProductId` and `Price` both are `int` so you cannot set text value in `int` field

So you should set the `ViewBag.ProductData, "Id", "Name"`  when ever you will run the script it will get the `int` value of `productId`

> Edit

if you want to get the data based on your Product id you have to make ajax call for that in jquery and you have to make action for that in controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetProduct(int pId)
        {
            var data = db.Products.Find(id);
            return Json(data);
        }
```

and your view would be

```
       @model CMSUsersAndRoles.Models.QuoteDetail

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "EditQuoteDetail";
        Layout = null;
    }

    @{
        var quoteId = (int)ViewData["QuoteId"];
        var quoteDetailId = (int)ViewData["QuoteDetailId"];
    }

     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>        
    <div id="row">
        <table>

            @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("quoteDetail"))

            {

                <tr>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuoteDetailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="ProductId", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.DropDownList("ProductList", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "ProductId", "Name"), new { @id = "ProductList" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="Price", @class = "form-control" } }
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteProduct", "QuoteViewModel", new { quoteId = Model.QuoteId, quoteDetailId = (Model.QuoteDetailId) },
                              new AjaxOptions
                              {
                                  HttpMethod = "POST",
                                  Confirm = "Are you Sure You Want to Delete " + Model.ProductName,
                                  OnSuccess = "RemoveRow"
                              },
                              new { @class = "btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" })
                            </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#ProductList').change(function () {
                    $.post("/QuoteViewModel/GetProduct", { pId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                        $('#ProductId').val(data.ProductId);
                        $('#Price').val(data.Price);
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136069/discussion-on-answer-by-usman-how-to-populate-text-boxes-based-on-dropdownlist-s).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening...

**(1)** `@Html.DropDownList("ProductName", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductData, "Name", "Name"), new { @id = "ProductName" })`

This line creates a `<select>` html element with an id of "ProductName" as expected; though the `value` of the `options` within that list are text values. Because you are using the "Name" for both the value and text of the `option`. For example:

```
<select id="ProductName" name="ProductName">
    <option value="Product 1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="Product 2">Product 2</option>
</select>
```

**(2)** `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="ProductId", @class = "form-control" } })`

Since you are using the EditorFor Html helper, it is trying to validate an integer (I assume) of the ProductId. Your javascript is trying to insert a String, like "Product 1".

**(3)** `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ListPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="Price", @class = "form-control" } })`

This has a slightly different issue. The ID of the HTML element will default to "ListPrice" and not be overridden by your @id property in the htmlAttributes object. Side question, do you mean to put `@id = "Price"` on the "ListPrice" element? Even if you fixup the ID attributes of these elements, you may still run into the data type issue from (2) above.

Try switching the target element to a TextBoxFor as a quick test.

Comment: I changed the EditorFor in examples 2) and 3) above to TextBoxFor and still no luck.  Nothing happens when I change the dropdown list selection.

Comment: Interesting... if all you did was change the EditorFor to TextBoxFor on those two lines, then I expect (2) to have worked, but (3) would not have because the id/naming issue mentioned. This is what happened for me when I recreated your scenario.

Comment: The javascript isn't firing, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Tough to figure out at this point without seeing all the files. All I can say is go over the files, start isolated things, removing extraneous items not relevant to the issue, basically use the process of elimination.

Comment: The files are here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/upnylj6pt8vpwsr/AABQXp6gS0rskgHFoaUWMVtva?dl=0  in case you are up for taking a look.

Comment: Ok, so the usage of the BeginCollectionItem helper is totally overtaking your html and inserting its own ID and Class attributes... like quoteDetail[2b71523b-3714-4e0d-bb83-e8fbb3b3a7fb].Price and quoteDetail_2b71523b-3714-4e0d-bb83-e8fbb3b3a7fb__ProductList. Since those appear to be generating random numbers, you probably won't be able to program against the ID. You'll have to reconsider the whole approach if you want to use the BeginCollectionItem helper.

Comment: use Chrome and the Chrome Dev Tools (F12) to inspect the actual HTML that is output in your browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input!  At least it's a relief to know what was causing the problem.  Any suggestions on a better way to proceed?

Comment: I would try to with a more straight ahead form posting approach with the BeginCollectionItem helper and understand the ins and outs for MVC Model Binding with collections. You could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/4-working-with-forms. Else I recommend a good ASP.NET MVC Book or video course.

Comment: I modified the javascript as follows:<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[id*="ProductList"]').change(function () {
                    $.post("/QuoteViewModel/GetProduct", { pId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                        $("[id*='ProductId']").val(data.ProductId);
                        $("[id*='Price']").val(data.Price);
                    });
                });
            });
            </script> but it still isn't working.  Any ideas?